# i want the program to ask user which payment method they wanna use (ONLINE/CARD) . But my code will show the wrong output

Tags: c

```
void Payment(){     
    do{

        printf("\nPLEASE ENTER YOUR PREFERED PAYMENT METHOD (ONLINE/CARD):");
        scanf("%s", &PaymentMethod);
        
        if(strcmp(PaymentMethod, "CARD")){
            
            Option = 1;
            printf("\nYOU HAVE SELECTED CARD PAYMENT METHOD");
        }
        else if(strcmp(PaymentMethod, "ONLINE")){

            Option = 1;    
            printf("\nYOU HAVE SELECTED ONLINE PAYMENT METHOD");
            printf("\n|DRUM E-BOOK ACCOUNT DETAILS : 6734-343-8621 (GOODBANK BERHAD)");
            printf("\nYOU HAVE SELECTED CARD PAYMENT METHOD");
            
        }
        else{
            printf("\nYOU HAVE ENTERED WRONG PAYMENT METHOD! PLEASE TRY AGAIN");
            Option=0;
        }
    }while(Option == 0);
    printf("\nPress any number to continue:");
    scanf("%d", &Option);
 Receipt();
```

each time i choose CARD , it will show the ONLINE output and show the opposite if i choose ONLINE

Comment: strcmp returns 0 on a match

Comment: Please read the documentation.

Comment: so what should i change?

Comment: It is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strcmp-wcscmp-mbscmp?view=msvc-170).

Comment: should i change to PaymentMethod == "CARD"  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(strcmp(PaymentMethod, "CARD"))
```

is equivalent to:

```
if (strcmp(PaymentMethod, "CARD") != 0)
```

`strcmp` returns `0` on equality, but the `if` construct considers zero to be false, so the block is never entered.

Change the condition to:

```
if (strcmp(PaymentMethod, "CARD") == 0)
```

---

*Re:* *"should i change to PaymentMethod == "CARD"?"*

*Answer:* No, you can't compare strings with the equality `==` operator. That only compares the pointer values.

---

Also note that you do not need to use the `&` operator with the `%s` format specifier in the call to `scanf`.